# bash combine columns after pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to remove the space between the numbers in Payout. I've been trying awk and sed but no success.

Input:

Name: John Doe
Type: Severance
Payout: 134 000
Year: 2015
--
Name: Jane Marilyn Doe
Type: Severance
Payout: 240 000
Year: 2015

#######################

Wanted output:

Name: John Doe
Type: Severance
Payout: 134000
Year: 2015
--
Name: Jane Marilyn Doe
Type: Severance
Payout: 240000
Year: 2015

Comment: And what did your trying look like?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '/^Payout/s/\s+//2g' file
```

This focuses on the line starting `Payout` and then removes the second or more groups of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options.  Sed has been answered, so here's awk:

`awk '$1 == "Payout:" {$0 = $1 " " $2$3} {print}' data file`

First, if it's a `Payout` line, it rewrites the line as you wanted.  Then, whether it's a `Payout` line or not, it prints the line, preserving the non-`Payout` lines as originally formatted.